# Wordfence plugin isn't installed though it's blocking the admin-ajax (403 forbidden)

Tags: wordpress

I've one website created using Wordpress. It was working fine until last 2 days, but it's started blocking the website from login into the admin panel for few users and also it's blocking admin-ajax for jupiter x theme who is able to logged in. I've tried to rename the Wordfence plugin to resolve the issue but to my surprise there isn't Wordfence plugin installed. How it is possible?

The payload of admin-ajax which is blocked by the Wordfence.
admin-ajax Payload =>
action: jupiterx_cp_load_pane_action
slug: install-plugins

Answer (score 0):

If you rename folder name then it will cause an error, you need to disable plugin from database.

You need to go on "wp_options" table and find the row called "active_plugins" and check 'option_value' of that row. There you can find the list of activate plugin. Delete wordfence plugin string from there and decrease one item into starting of the string. for example if at first time there is a "a:9", after you remove wordfence line from 'option_value' you need to set "a:8".

Then update that particular row of the database. and wordfence plugin will deactive.

Note: Kindly take backup of your whole database before perform this steps.

Comment: Hi @Vimal Usadadiya - Thanks for the reply but as I mentioned in my question that there isn't wordpress plugin installed in my wordpress setup.

Comment: Is there any cache plugin intalled or cache system from theme is active?